# Selection of a “best” regression model using differet approaches

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, model-selection

I need help with the following question.

[image]

I am really lost, so any help/hint would be much appreciated!
I am aware that for best fit model, we are looking for higher $R^2_{Adj}$, smaller $MS_{res}$, PRESS (Prediction error sum of squares), AIC (Akaike Information Criterion) and BIC (Bayesian Information Criterion).

Comment: It's a [shame](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290) students are still being given these questions in stats classes.

Comment: The biggest problem I am having is "efficiency". For example, for part (a) we have that Partial F-test = SSres(red) - SSres(full)/p / SSres(full)/(n-k), and so it takes ages to compute the p-value for all the 6 models.Then the same problem comes up again in the next points. Is there a quicker way?